# Create a new Variable of values of another variable-multilevel regression

Tags: r, variables, multi-level, mutation, multilevel-analysis

I am up to create a multilevel analysis (and I am a total newbie).

In this analysis I want to test if a high value of a predictor( here:senseofhumor) (numeric value - transfered into "high","low","medium") would predict the (numeric)outcome more than the other (numeric)predictors (senseofhomor-seriousness-friednlyness).
I have a dataset with many people and groups and want to compare the outcome between the groups regarding the influence of **SenseofhumorHIGH**

The code for that might look like this

```
RandomslopeEC <- lme(criteria(timepoint1) ~ senseofhumor + seriousness + friendlyness , data = DATA, random = ~ **SenseofhumorHIGH**|group)
```

For that reason I created values "high" "low" "medium" for my numeric predictor via

```
library(tidyverse)
DATA <- DATA %>% 
  mutate(predictorNew = case_when(senseofhumor< quantile(senseofhumor, 0.5) ~ 'low', 
                      senseofhumor > quantile(senseofhumor, 0.75)~'high', 
                      TRUE ~ 'med'))
```

Now they look like this:

| Person | Group | senseofhumor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | low |
| 7 | 1 | high |
| 87 | 7 | low |
| 764 | 45 | high |

Now I realized i might need to cut this variable values in separate variables if I want to test my idea.

Do any of you know how to generate variables, that they may look like this?

| Person | Group | senseofhumorHIGH | senseofhumorMED | senseofhumorLOW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 87 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 764 | 45 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 51 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 362 | 9 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 87 | 27 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Does this make any sense to you regarding my approach? Or do you have a better idea?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to learning R. You will want to convert these types of variables to "factors," and R will be able to process them accordingly. To do that, use `as.factor(variable)` - so for you it may be `DATA$senseofhumor <- as.factor(DATA$senseofhumor)`. If you need to convert multiple columns, you can use:

```
factor_cols <- c("Var1","Var2","Var3") # list columns you want as factors
DATA[factor_cols] <- lapply(DATA[factor_cols], as.factor)
```

Since you are new, note that this forum is typically for questions that cant be easily found online. This question is relatively routine and more details can be found with a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=model+r+using+factor&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=AOaemvIChHHuG1iE6h9uNXfRiNmkdfhkaQ%3A1641472208735&ei=0ODWYeauLK-aptQP5o2omAQ&ved=0ahUKEwjm1qO_kJ31AhUvjYkEHeYGCkMQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=model+r+using+factor&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BQgAEM0CSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUPcLWJYPYIMRaAFwAngAgAGAAYgBrgSSAQM1LjGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz). While SO is a great place to learn R, you may be penalized by the SO community in the future for routine questions like this. Just trying to help ensure you keep learning!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the path. Thanks also for the hint regarding questions here. Maybe I searched google in a wrong way. But I will keep in mind to post more technic related stuff here. Maybe more for errors or visualising. Thanks again :)